# Need help understanding this inheritence hierarchy

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I am looking at a complex and generic legacy framework which I will eventually need to extend, first up however is to simply understand it, and I'm struggling to do so due to the inheritence hierarchy and structure.

This all forms part of the inner workings of a WCF services stack, handling the requests, responses, etc.

I've included only the class signatures and their constructors as a sample as the inner functionality is of no concern.

```
public sealed class ProcessDerived : ProcessBase<Filter, RequestExternal, RequestItemExternal, ResponseCallBack, ResponseInternal>
{
    public ProcessDerived(ProcessManager Manager) : base(Manager) { }
}

public abstract class ProcessBase<TFilter, TRequestExternal, TRequestItemExternal, TResponseCallBack, TResponseInternal>
    : ProcessBaseSync<TFilter, TRequestExternal, TRequestItemExternal, TResponseCallBack, TResponseInternal>
    where TFilter : FilterBase
    where TRequestExternal : class
    where TRequestItemExternal : class
    where TResponseCallBack : class
    where TResponseInternal : ProcessResponseBase
{
    protected ProcessBase(ProcessManager Manager) : base(Manager) { }
}

public abstract class ProcessBaseSync<TFilter, TRequestExternal, TRequestItemExternal, TResponseCallBack, TResponseInternal>
    : ProcessBaseCache<TFilter, TRequestExternal, TRequestItemExternal, object, TResponseCallBack, TResponseInternal, CacheKeyBase>
    where TFilter : FilterBase
    where TRequestExternal : class
    where TRequestItemExternal : class
    where TResponseCallBack : class
    where TResponseInternal : ProcessResponseBase
{
    protected ProcessBaseSync(ProcessManager Manager) : base(Manager) { }
}

public abstract class ProcessBaseCache<TFilter, TRequestExternal, TRequestItemExternal, TResponseImmediate, TResponseCallBack, TResponseInternal, TCacheKey>
    : IProcess, IProcess<TFilter, TResponseInternal>, IProcess<TResponseCallBack>
    where TFilter : FilterBase
    where TRequestExternal : class
    where TRequestItemExternal : class
    where TResponseImmediate : class
    where TResponseCallBack : class
    where TResponseInternal : ProcessResponseBase
    where TCacheKey : CacheKeyBase
{
    private ProcessManager _manager;

    protected ProcessBaseCache(ProcessManager Manager)
    {
        _manager = Manager;
    }
}
```

The main questions I have:

1) What is the technical term used to describe this multiple inheritence structure, like seen on the first line: "ProcessDerived : ProcessBase".

It reminds me of tuples, but I don't understand whats happening here on a technical level. Is this just a way to get around the multiple inheritence limitation?

2) Does it inherit from "ProcessBase" as well as all the type parameters next to it?

3) What is the purpose of adding ": base(XYZ)" to the constructor? Is this simply a requirement to match the class inheritence (constructor mimicking the class signature)? I don't understand why this is required.

This complex 4-tier hierarchy seems very unecessary and feels impossible to follow.

I'm clearly missing some fundamental C# knowledge here.

Comment: 1) there is nothing  that look like multiple inheritance here. Only 2 interfaces on the last class.

Comment: 2) is constructor chaining. Omit it and you'll get an error that the base class constructor cannot be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) What is the technical term used to describe this multiple inheritence structure, like seen on the first line: "ProcessDerived : `ProcessBase`.

That's single inheritance. `ProcessDerived` inherits from `ProcessBase<Filter, RequestExternal, RequestItemExternal, ResponseCallBack, ResponseInternal>`.

> 2) Does it inherit from "ProcessBase" as well as all the type parameters next to it?

`ProcessBase<Filter, RequestExternal, RequestItemExternal, ResponseCallBack, ResponseInternal>` is a (closed generic) type. ProcessDerived inherits from it.

`ProcessBase<TFilter, TRequestExternal, TRequestItemExternal, TResponseCallBack, TResponseInternal>` is the corresponding open generic type -- the type parameters `TFilter` etc haven't yet been specified.

> 3) What is the purpose of adding ": base(XYZ)" to the constructor? Is this simply a requirement to match the class inheritence (constructor mimicking the class signature)? I don't understand why this is required.

When you subclass is instantiated, it needs to call one of the base class's constructors. If the base class has a parameterless constructor, this is called implicitly. If it doesn't, you need to explicitly call one of its constructors, passing all necessary parameters, using `: base(...)`.

> I'm clearly missing some fundamental C# knowledge here.

I suspect the knowledge you're missing is around **generics** - you seem to think that generic types, and generic type parameters, are involved in inheritance.

Comment: Thank you @canton7. You're right, generics are throwing me for a loop. I thought that ProcessDerived was deriving from some sort of collection of classes (which doesn't make sense) instead of one class with multiple generic type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first (and second) question, you can extend a single base class and then implement several interfaces, but the code you posted only extends a single base class. It just happens that `ProcessBase` accepts 5 different types, but it's still one class.

---

As for your third question, they added [`base`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) because the class extends a base class that doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

Here's a simpler example demonstrating the same concept. The `Person` class has a single ctor expecting a name, so any class that extends it must provide that parameter via a call to `base()`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

    public Employee(string name, DateTime hireDate) : base(name)
    {
        HireDate = hireDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Grant. I understand it now.. As pointed out by @canton7, I'm having issues fully understanding generics and where it comes into play and in this case the 5 type parameters led me to think its deriving from a base collection of 5 classes, instead of just one class with multiple interfaces.